# Firebase Persistence Data Not Loading Offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have firebase initialised in my acitivity.

```
    mFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebase.getReference("buses");
    mBusReference = mDatabaseReference.child(mSelectedBusModel.getRegistrationNo());
    mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         ...
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.e("Data", "Cancelled");
         databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    mBusReference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```

I have a singleton that extends Application and inside the onCreate method I have enabled firebase persistence:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Now my problem is when I go offline and reopen my activity the data has not been cached, nothing loads.  I have read the docs and done everything mentioned but it still does not work.

What I want to do is enable my app to cache data already loaded from firebase so it's always available even after the app has been closed and re-opened.

Please note no errors are displayed in my console.

Comment: Calling `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` means that Firebase stores to disk any data it has recently seen. In your test, did your app load the data before you went offline?

Comment: Yes it did. I made sure of it.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure why it wouldn't load in that case. The code you shared looks fine at first glance. You might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the output for something suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Just using *setPersistenceEnabled(true)* doesn't cut it. You must change your listener because you save the data in your disk but you dont handle them. You must use something like this (it was taken from firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) i have used it for my app and worked for me).

--- edit ---

If you want to keep your data synced you must use `ref.keepSynced(true);`. The below piece of code is what i used to retrieve cached data from reference. When i am offline the child returns the values normally.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, for replying, I'm confused though, change my listener to what? I'm already using ValueEventListener.  Your code within the listener only seems to check connection status and save timestamp, can you please explain more about it and what it has to do with offline mode and which part of my code I'm supposed to change exactly.